# How to get Intellisense recognize SSVE?

Tags: c#, nancy

I've installed Nancy and intended to use the built-in Super Simple View Engine for rendering my views, however Intellisense completely fails to recognize the syntax in a self hosted project. For the Razor View Engine, the NancyFX documentation points out which build providers one needs to declare in app.config to get the Razor View Engine recognized by Intellisense, however with SSVE, the documentation lacks of that part.

Does anyone knows a way to get me out of the old notepad-style age?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no intellisense for SSVE - there is a Nancy ReSharper plugin, which adds a lot of features, but I don't believe that's one of them.